# How can I make a custom button also accept directives like matStepperPrevious in angular 4 material

Tags: angular

I have made a custom button and it works fine for normal function calls. But can I make that same button work with directives like matStepperPrevious.

I have made a demo of what I want to achieve here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyyg3k?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Regards. Ole Bille

Answer (score 1):

You cant :( the selector for the matStepperPrevious is :

button[matStepperPrevious] ( cf [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepperPrevious) ) , that mean a  with a "matStepperPrevious" attribute

But as your app-button component doesn't seem to have any real template, you could certainly refactor it to be a directive?

I forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msafnd) transforming your component to a directive that will `fire` on click.

EDIT : i edited the stackblitz to show an example on how to disable the button from the directive

Comment: Hi Pierre.
Could a directive like that also disable the button if the directive could see a variable on a service was true?
And thx alot for your reply =)
Regards Ole Bille

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass them, but, since your main module `app` module has loaded `mat` modules, you can use those directives directly inside of your custom made directive, I've removed the passing of that directive and just used that directive directly on your own, here is the changed code: [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rknxpu?file=app/button/button.component.html)

Comment: Hi Nikola
This was my fallback plan. Id prefer if I didnt have to create additional button componts but it might be the only solution. The reason Ive made a custom button is because it "listens" to a spinnerService. if the spinner is running I disable the button in the custom component. But If it is not possible to use the same button for both usecases then This is how Ill solve it. Thx for answering.